# Postfix pipe mail at user level

Tags: postfix, pipe

I am trying to filter mail at the user level. I have CentOS and Postfix installed.

I managed to install a filter on the server and its working great, except, instead of filtering by user, all emails (sent and received) for all users are getting through the filter. (I want only emails sent to bounce@example.com to go through the filter).

I have added to `master.cf`:

```
myhook unix - n n - - pipe flags=F user=nils_filter argv=/path to/postfix.php ${sender} ${size} ${recipient}
smtp inet n - - - - smtpd -o content_filter=myhook:
pickup fifo n - - 60 1 pickup -o content_filter=myhook:
```

`main.cf` has:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/access,permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination
```

and I updated the `access` file with:

```
bounce@example.com FILTER myhook
```

After running `postmap` and reloading, it is working for the entire example.com domain (all emails sent and received on smtp are getting piped through the filter I setup).

Could you point me in the right direction where I might be wrong?

Comment: Just responding to the title of your question ; a `.forward` file per user or an entry in the aliases file which pipes mail to a script `| ./script` maybe?

Answer (score 1):

All emails got piped into because you specify `content_filter` on smtpd and pickup in master.cf.

Solution:

- Remove the string `-o content_filter=myhook:` from master.cf
- Put `myhook` in access file with *proper syntax*

  ```
  bounce@example.com FILTER myhook:
  ```

Reference: [man access](http://www.postfix.org/access.5.html)

Comment: @Nash, if it works, please accept the answer by clicking the checkmark right beside it.